# Making a component based app using IoC and CBD

Tags: language-agnostic, inversion-of-control

I have read quite a bit about IoC and Component Based Design. However I am a bit unsure of what the best way it to design my interfaces.

I am not sure how coarse or fine-graded they should be. Consider the Shipment component as an example:

- The shipment component can be configured with some settings
- The user can add items to and remove items from the shipment
- The user can perform some functions on the shipment  that changes it's state e.g. Ready For Shipment, Authorise, Despatch, Invoice, etc.

The simplest interface for this module could be as follows (pseudocode):

```
public interface IShipment
{
  AddItem(Item);
  RemoveItem(Item);

  ReadyForShipment();
  Authorise();
  Despatch();
  Invoice();
}
```

However, I am not sure whether this is in fact the proper interface. Maybe we should separate them:

```
public interface IShipmentContents
{
  AddItem(Item);
  RemoveItem(Item);
}

public interface IShipmentActions
{
  ReadyForShipment();
  Authorise();
  Despatch();
  Invoice();
}
```

Or we can take it to the extreme where each of the actions become an interface and thus us being able to inject concrete implementations of 
each action instead of a group of them.

Can anone point me to some reading material to help me understand the application of IoC and CBD in a real world app?

Comment: Related: stackoverflow.com/questions/2045904/dependency-inject-di-friendly-library